# Was Margot Having an Affair with Eli?

Tags: plot-explanation, character, the-royal-tenenbaums

The [Wikipedia Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Royal_Tenenbaums) on The Royal Tenenbaums claims that Margot and Eli were having an affair, but I find this somewhat difficult to believe. Other than the one scene in which Eli leaves Margot's room by window, there didn't seem to be any indication of this. In fact, during the entire movie, it seems that Margot is quite emotionally distant from Eli.

So, are there any good indications that Margot and Eli were having an affair? Note that I'm not really willing to believe the claims of the private investigators (it's not clear to me why they couldn't have just made things up; beyond that their findings seem to contradict Margot's secretive lifestyle.)